# How do I use Python to start cmd in Windows at specific location and set prompt colors?

Tags: python, cmd, colors

I'm working in an environment where I most of the time have two terminal windows running beside each other. One of them is running a Python program together with a SQL Server. The other terminal window is just a regular Windows command prompt. To make it easier to keep these windows apart from each other I want to set the colors for the one that is running the Python program. I know how to do that with the following code:

```
from os import system
t1 = 'Some instructions that I need to print out for other users when the prompt is opened.'
print(t1)
system('cmd /k color 17')
```

This will start the terminal at the location where the Python script is. Since this is not where most of the users wants to start, I try to handle there request by changing the code to:

```
system('cmd /k cd P:\\Some\\other\\location' & color 17')
```

This will give me the wished start location but the prompt colors will be the default black and white. If I change the order I will get the correct colors but I will start at the wrong location (the start location is the location where the python script is located).

I've also tried:

```
from subprocess import call
call('start', shell = True, cwd = 'P:\\Some\\other\\location')
```

This gives me the correct start location but I can't figure out how I should do to change the colors.

Notice that I dont want to change the colors depending on results, just make a constant change so it will be easier to quikly see which terminal window who runs what.

The Python installation is 3.8.5 and it is in a closed environment without internet connection, so I can't download any special modules or packages by my self.

Comment: Thanks K J! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
from os import system

system('cmd /k "cd /d C:\\Some\\Other\\Location & color BackgroundcolorFontcolor"')
```

will give the desired result.

Example:

```
from os import system

system('cmd /k "cd /d C:\\Programs\\Python\\ProjectX & color 5e"')
```

This code will launch a terminal which have a purple background and yellow text at the location for "ProjectX" at the C-drive.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried changing directory inside python instead of cmd ?

```
oldir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(newdir)
call(...)
os.chdir(oldir)
```

Comment: No, but I have now. :) That gives me the same result as my call-syntax in my question or am I missing something here? I do get the correct start location but I dont understand how I should do to get the correct colors? And when I'm using subprocess.call instead of os.system I dont get my instruction print out? I gueass it just "flashes" by because I get something that opens and closes directly on the screen.